# Ubuntu 18.04 - ubuntu unable to install / cannot perform the following task

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

For the last few days, evey time I try and install a  new app, I get

```
ubuntu unable to install:
cannot perform the following task:
```

... with no app name nor task listed.
I tried

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

no better results afterwards.
Being extremely rookie, I'm not sure what to try next.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help!

After a few exchanges here and there I was recommended to add this information:

**cat /etc/apt/sources.list**

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

**ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d -1**

```
megasync.list
megasync.list.distUpgrade
megasync.list.save
slack.list
slack.list.save
teamviewer.list
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the apt proxy settings:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ap...e_a_http-proxy

Note use the command

Code:

sudo -H gedit

instead of gksudo, as gksudo no longer exists.

Edit: since the link doesn't exist try this

Apt loads all configuration files under /etc/apt/apt.conf.d. We can create a configuration specifically for our proxy there, keeping it separate from all other configurations.

Create a new configuration file named proxy.conf.

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Open the proxy.conf file in a text editor.

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Add the following line to set your HTTP proxy.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
```

Add the following line to set your HTTPS proxy.

```
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
```

Save your changes and exit the text editor.

Your proxy settings will be applied the next time your run Apt.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, the link on help ubuntu doesn't exist....

Comment: I have edited my answer ,please try it out and let me know if it works and don't forget to upvote and mark as right answer :P

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.No change whatsoever...